# Joining 2 tables without a primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in Oracle SQL. I have 2 data sets.

One has customer data and the other is just a list of brand names

How can I join these two tables so that I can have each customer with every brand name

For example:

```
Customer_Number  
---------------
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  


Brand_Name  
-----------
A  
B  
C  
D  
E
```

I want my final output to look like this

```
Customer_Number  Brand_Name  
---------------------------
1 A  
1 B  
1 C  
1 D  
1 E   
2 A  
2 B  
2 C  
2 D  
2 E  
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a `cross join`:

```
select c.Customer_Number, b.brand_name
from customers c cross join
     brands b
```

Comment: or simply `from customers c, brands b` at least for Oracle